# Neo4j: Data modelling and cypher, Paths independent of node combinations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently trying to solve a, what I thought simple, problem. I want model booster pack combinations from a TCG. Lets say a booster pack can contain 6 common, 3 uncommon and 1 rare rune. I want to know all combinations of rare, common and uncommon cards which are possible.

In my first iteration I tried a hierarchical graph structure. The rare cards were connected to all uncommon ones, and the uncommon one to all commons. Now I start my query with  an rare card, go from there to three uncommon ones and then from an uncommon one to 6 common ones.

In the second iteration I tried grouping the cards by rarity. All rare cards were connected to all other rare ones and so on.

In both iterations I had the problem, that my queries didnt finish.
For an expansion consisting of 57 cards, I got about 16000 combination of rares und uncommons alone. When I try to add the commons nodes to the path, cypher explodes. Part of the problem is, that I get "duplicates" like

```
Path1 = rare1->uncommon1, rare1->uncommon2, rare1->uncommon2
Path2 = rare1->uncommon2, rare1->uncommon1, rare1->uncommon3
Path3 = rare1->uncommon3, rare1->uncommon2, rare1->uncommon1
Path4 = rare1->uncommon3, rare1->uncommon1, rare1->uncommon2
```

and so on
Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Please create a sample data set at console.neo4j.org. Once you setup the data, click on the "share" button on top right of the screen. You can share a link to your session.

Comment: Seriously I dont even know how this would help or if this is the right approach. But here you go: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=9kono5
Now I'd need a query that returns a path which is independent of the order of its elements.

Comment: Right now I do something like Match rare-->u1, rare-->u2, rare-->u3 which for the above graph would return all 6 combinations(but I only want one, since I dont care about the order of elements)

Comment: What I feel what I would need, is a way to compare paths; a way to assure that the nodes of a path are not equal to a previously matched path

Comment: @PhilBa This is more/less the same issue as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660176/cypher-do-not-repeat-same-results/18150109#18150109

Comment: Thank you very much, in the end I solved it by modeling/inserting my nodes in a specific manner.